# Mouse gets stuck in drag mode when mouse leaves stage

Tags: reactjs, drag-and-drop, mouse, draggable, konvajs

I'm using React-konva.

I implemented a horizontal control with a draggable handle.

I have a Stage, a Layer, and the handle is a Group within that. The group representing the handle is draggable, with drag positions restricted to horizontal movement.

When I drag the handle, it works OK, but when the mouse leaves the Stage, dragging gets stuck: even if I release the mouse button, the handle is still dragged (the handle Group is still getting onDragMove events). If I click within the Stage, the mouse is released and dragging is stopped.

How should I handle this? Should I detect that the mouse has left a control and respond in some way?

Here are the relevant parts of the code:

```
restrictDragToHorizontal(pos) {
   return {x: pos.x, y: this.getAbsolutePosition().y};
}

render() {
...
return (
  <div className="Timeline">
  </div>
    <Stage width={...} height={...}>
      <Layer>
            <Group name="handle" draggable={true} x={...} y={...} 
              onDragMove={ (event) => {
                ...
              }}
              onDragEnd={ (event) => {
                ...
              }}
              dragBoundFunc={this.restrictDragToHorizontal}
            >
              <Rect ... />
              <Circle ... />
              <Text ... />
            </Group>
      </Layer>
    </Stage>
)
}
```

Comment: Can you make small online demo of your issue?

Comment: Do you use some iframes?

Comment: @lavrton - I assume you listen for mouseup on the document or body elements in the Konvas.js lib ? You also should ask if the OP has a cancelDefault/propagatiion listener too.

Comment: @lavrton No, I don't use iframes.

Comment: @balintn I think a demo is required.

Comment: In the meantime, the control and its parent were re-styled, and the issue is now gone. Now I can drag the mouse outside, when the mouse cursor returns it works correctly. Can't really tell what's different now.